# Create random pattern from two colors

Tags: javascript, css, plugins

I want to create an header background with this type of blurry effect. There is any library to make this type of stuff randomly, using two colors as source, or an image?

```
.myElement { 
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAADCAYAAABfwxXFAAAAYklEQVQYVwFXAKj/AUkdUf8hDh8AXFpKAOXO1gAp+RYAIRgdAJnNwwABs2an/+LZ3gDqCvcAPVVLANm6xAA3CxYAMyIuAAGNTY3/6evjAOT99QAtRTkAHR4UAMuaugAyFSkAiWIgFtwHkmoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
  width:1000px;
  height:500px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6wp1qyr9/

Comment: @artgb I am not looking for an algorithm.

Comment: You could do it easy enough with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but I found this, and thought it might give you a place to start: [Generate a monochrome bitmap image in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/vukicevic/8112515)

Also found this library for generating PNGs in JS: [Generating images in JavaScript](https://github.com/zholos/js_bitmap)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CSS blur property to blur out images. For example:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<img class="blur" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*YRINRZFr0E1FRJ4JpizEMw.jpeg">
```

Alternatively, scale up a part of the image:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;


function drawPartialImage() {
  var base64 = this.result;
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = base64;
  image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(
      image,
      Math.floor(image.width * Math.random()),
      Math.floor(image.height * Math.random()),
      12,
      12,
      0,
      0,
      canvas.width,
      canvas.height);
  }
}

document.getElementById('fileInput').onchange = function(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = drawPartialImage.bind(reader);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0;"><br>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
```